# Ruby function to remove all white spaces?

Tags: ruby, string

What is the Ruby function to remove **all** white spaces? I'm looking for something kind of like PHP's `trim()`?

Comment: Your question is not clear: Do you want to remove all whitespace or do you want to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace?

Comment: PHP's [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) strips whitespace "_from the beginning and end of a string_" (as stated within [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)), it does not remove "all whitespaces".

Comment: When in doubt, look at the Ruby online documentation for the String class (see .strip below).

Comment: Note that all answers using `String#strip` or matching `/\s+/` will remove only ASCII whitespace. If you want to ensure any non-ASCII whitespace is captured too (e.g. HTML's `&nbsp`) see the oddly unpopular answer from @EBooker.

Comment: Pity that such great answers cannot get the final dignity of one being accepted

Answer (score 928):

If you want to remove only leading and trailing whitespace (like PHP's trim) you can use `.strip`, but if you want to remove ***all*** whitespace, you can use `.gsub(/\s+/, "")` instead .

Comment: Does "/\s+/" simple mean whitespace?

Comment: \s+ means 1 or more whitespace characters (space, newline, tab). The // surrounding show that it's a regular expression.

Comment: also note that ActiveSupport (rails) adds `String#remove(pattern)` which is a shortcut to `String#gsub(pattern, '')` (plus a destructive `remove!` version). Quite handy.

Comment: Technically, `\s` means `" "`, `"\n"`, `"\t"`, `"\r"`, `"\f"` or`"\v"`. However, only the first 3 (or possibly 4) are even remotely common.

Comment: Note: The `'+'` in `"\s+"` is not necessary here, as all whitespace will be removed with just `gsub("/\s/", '')`

Comment: @LouisSayers Technically true. My preference is to communicate intent; "replace all runs of whitespace with empty string" seems more direct to me (and possibly an insignificant bit less string manipulation) than "replace each whitespace character with empty string". YMMV.

Comment: Neither `.strip` nor the `gsub` alternative remove unicode whitespace characters... `"\u00a0".strip.length` returns 1. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810885/145725 for an answer that works correctly in these situations.

Answer (score 564):

```
s = "I have white space".delete(' ')
```

And to emulate PHP's `trim()` function:

```
s = "   I have leading and trailing white space   ".strip
```

Comment: this is much more readable than the regex, why is it not as popular?

Comment: @ckarbass: Because many people prefer overly complex solutions to simple problems.  It goes away with experience.

Comment: I think it is because many people are actually looking for strip. Even the one that only mentions strip is higher than this entry.

Comment: @JasonAxelson: You're riht about `strip`, it's a better alternative than what I posted (and I commented such and voted that response up... wow, almost three years ago now).  The thing is, many people rush to use regular expressions when it's overkill. They do accomplish different things however.

Comment: @ckarbass @Ed S. It isn't as popular because it isn't the same. The original question used the phrase "all whitespace", which includes tabs, newlines, etc. This proposed answer will not remove those other whitespace characters. As for "overly complex", I suggest comparing the simple regular expression to `.delete(' ').delete('\t').delete('\n') ...`, which is overly verbose and provides many opportunities for typos and errors of omission.

Comment: @joel.neely: I answered this question a long time ago, but read the question again, this time more carefully.  The OP asked for *"a function to remove all whitespace"*, but then asked for *"something like PHP's trim()"*.  So, it's a bit difficult to know exactly what they want here.  `trim()` certainly does not remove newlines and other whitespace characters.  You're choosing one interpretation of a vague question.

Comment: @joel.neely: That said, I agree that a solution which goes beyond the literal interpretation of the question is a better one in this case (i.e., a regex removing all characters which would constitute whitespace rather than a string of `delete()` calls.)

Comment: @ckarbass: Because regex may be used to do also other more complicated things and the same regex is more likely to work in different language than this function.

Comment: @Bulwersator: And if neither of those things are requirements then you're simply wasting time implementing a more complicated solution than you need.  YAGNI

Comment: but this removes only `spaces`, not all `white spaces`

Comment: @Gavriel: Yeah I'm pretty sure that was covered six and a half years ago.

Comment: It's not necessary to call `delete` several times. As seen in @ndnenkov answer, you can call `delete(" \t\r\n")`

Answer (score 199):

[`String#strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-strip) - remove all whitespace from the start and the end.

[`String#lstrip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-lstrip) - just from the start.

[`String#rstrip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-rstrip) - just from the end.

[`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-chomp) (with no arguments) - deletes line separators (`\n` or `\r\n`) from the end.

[`String#chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-chop) - deletes the last character.

[`String#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-delete) - `x.delete(" \t\r\n")` - deletes all listed whitespace.

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) - `x.gsub(/[[:space:]]/, '')` - removes all whitespace, including [unicode ones](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).

---

**Note**: All the methods above return a new string instead of mutating the original. If you want to change the string in place, call the corresponding method with `!` at the end.

Comment: The String#delete example appears to use a regex, but `\s` is in quotes instead of slashes. Also I couldn't find any mention in the documentation that delete can take a regex as an argument.

Comment: @slothbear, it's not a regex, it's a small set of patterns that resemble regexes. As for the documentation [`#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-delete) is said to work similarly to [`#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-count). You can try it in the console as well.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new. And also thanks for the reminder to try things in the smallest possible context (command line).

Comment: @slothbear, while the thing about about `#delete` patterns is true, `\s` in general just refers to space: `"\s" == ' ' # => true`. Hence the previous version only removed spaces. Updated my answer.

Comment: delete returns `nil` when no space is found.

Comment: @juliangonzalez, `#delete` doesn't, `#delete!` does.

Comment: Only the final example in this answer catches the dread ASCII 160 'non-breaking space', the bane of web scrapers. `#strip` does not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859438/how-do-i-remove-a-non-breaking-space-in-ruby

Comment: Apparently, the difference between `[[:space:]]` as in `.gsub(/[[:space:]]/, '')` and `\s` [as in `.gsub(/\s+/, "")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634814/4575793) is that the first [remove unicode whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces/37148258#comment109945101_1634814), while the latter [only replaces `" "`, `"\n"`, `"\t"`, `"\r"`, `"\f"` and `"\v"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces/37148258#comment64205029_1634814)

Answer (score 180):

Related answer:

```
"   clean up my edges    ".strip
```

returns

```
"clean up my edges"
```

Comment: That's the one I forgot about.  I knew there was a method to remove whitespace which would do so by default if no arguments were passed. +1

Comment: This is equivalent to trim. Please refer to the quote from @Tadeck above.

Comment: If there is a possibility that the variable is `nil`, be sure to run `.to_s` method before running strip so that the strip method does not raise an error. Ex. `str=nil; str.to_s.strip #=> ""`

Comment: I prefer some_data.strip! if some_data.is_a? String

Answer (score 142):

**If you are using Rails/ActiveSupport**, you can use `squish` method. It removes white space on both ends of the string and groups multiple white space to single space.

For eg.

```
" a  b  c ".squish
```

will result to:

```
"a b c"
```

Check [this reference from api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: I think this answer was enough explained and the fact that link was reference since the answer itself was clear explained. This function was good, thanks

Comment: This is from ActiveSupport. You don't need all of Rails to use it, but you do need at least ActiveSupport and a
`require 'active_support/core_ext/string/filters'`

Comment: To be clear, this is _any_ whitespace.  E.g. `"a \t \n \f \r \v b".squish == "a b"`

Answer (score 106):

```
"1232 23 2 23 232 232".delete(' ')
=> "123223223232232"
```

Delete works faster =)

```
user         system     total      real
gsub, s      0.180000   0.010000   0.190000 (0.193014)
gsub, s+     0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (0.196408)
gsub, space  0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (0.222711)
gsub, join   0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (0.193478)
delete       0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (0.045157)
```

Comment: but this removes only `spaces`, not all `white spaces`

Comment: `delete(" \t\r\n")` will take care of typical whitespace, and is still faster than gsub.

Comment: [Technically, `\s` means one of these 6: `\n\t \r\f\v`. However, only the first 3 (or possibly 4) are even remotely common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces/37148258#comment64205029_1634814). So **tl;dr:** `delete(" \n\t\r\f\v")` is the faster equivalent of `.gsub(/\s/, "")`.

Answer (score 50):

It's a bit late, but anyone else googling this page might be interested in this version -

If you want to clean up a chunk of pre-formatted text that a user may have cut & pasted into your app somehow, but preserve the word spacing, try this:

```
content = "      a big nasty          chunk of     something

that's been pasted                        from a webpage       or something        and looks 

like      this

"

content.gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip

#=> "a big nasty chunk of something that's been pasted from a webpage or something and looks like this"
```

Comment: One could also use Rails' `squish` method: http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish

Comment: Or if you don't have Rails, and you don't have newlines, `squeeze(" ")` might work.

Answer (score 50):

Ruby's `.strip` method performs the PHP equivalent to `trim()`.

To remove all whitespace:

```
"  leading    trailing   ".squeeze(' ').strip
=> "leading trailing"
```

@Tass made me aware that my original answer removes duplicate letters in succession - YUCK! I've since switched to the squish method which is smarter about such occurrences if using the Rails framework.

```
require 'active_support/all'
"  leading    trailing   ".squish
=> "leading trailing"

"  good    men   ".squish
=> "good men"
```

Cite: http://apidock.com/rails/String/squish

Comment: This will remove "joined" duplicate characters. `"good men".squeeze.strip` will return `"god men"`

Answer (score 31):

To remove whitespace on both sides:

> Kind of like php's trim()

```
"   Hello  ".strip
```

To remove all spaces:

```
"   He    llo  ".gsub(/ /, "")
```

To remove all whitespace:

```
"   He\tllo  ".gsub(/\s/, "")
```

Answer (score 27):

```
" Raheem Shaik ".strip
```

It will removes left & right side spaces.
This code would give us: `"Raheem Shaik"`

Answer (score 24):

`split.join` will blast all spaces anywhere in the string.

```
"  a b  c    \nd  \t   ".split.join
> "abcd"
```

It's easy to type and remember, so it's nice on the console and for quick hacking. Arguably not welcome in serious code though as it masks the intent.

*(Based on Piotr's comment in [Justicle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634763/18706) above.)*

Comment: Many, many thanks for this comment :-) This is the only method that works if you have long string which looks like a paragraph.

Answer (score 20):

Also don't forget:

```
$ s = "   I have white space   ".split
=> ["I", "have", "white", "space"]
```

Comment: So s.split.join will do the job.

Comment: This is nice when iterating: `[" Hello World", "Big Giraffe "].map(&:split).map(&:join) #=> ["HelloWorld", "BigGiraffe"]`

Answer (score 20):

To remove all whitespace characters, including non-ASCII ones (e.g., non-breaking space), in a string you could try using `gsub` with `:space` as the matcher and `""` (empty string) as the replacement:

```rb
string = "   Some Special Text Values ".gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, "")
puts '[' + string + ']' # "[SomeSpecialTextValues]

string = "   em spaces   ".gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, "")
puts '[' + string.strip + ']' # [emspaces]
```

To remove leading and trailing whitespace characters, you can try:

```rb
string = "   em spaces   "
 .gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "")
 .gsub(/[[:space:]]+$/, "")
puts '[' + string.strip + ']' # [em spaces]

string = "   em spaces   ".strip
puts '[' + string.strip + ']' # [   em spaces]
```

Note how `strip` only removes the trailing whitespaces (i.e., `SPACE U+0020`) while leaving the leading whitespaces (i.e., `EM SPACE U+2003`) as-is. That's because `strip` only removes ASCII whitespace characters.

Comment: This is actually the best answer IMHO, as in the wild HTML `&nbsp` and any other non-ASCII whitespaces will **not** be removed by `String#strip` or matched by `/\s/`. See the section entitled "POSIX bracket expressions" in the [Regexp docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Regexp.html)

Comment: Instead of creating another similar answer, I decided to piggyback on yours, EBooker. Great job!

Answer (score 10):

Use gsub or delete. The difference is gsub could remove tabs, while delete cannot. Sometimes you do have tabs in files which are added by the editors.

```
a = "\tI have some whitespaces.\t"
a.gsub!(/\s/, '')  #=>  "Ihavesomewhitespaces."
a.gsub!(/ /, '')   #=>  "\tIhavesomewhitespaces.\t"
a.delete!(" ")     #=>  "\tIhavesomewhitespaces.\t"
a.delete!("/\s/")  #=>  "\tIhavesomewhitespaces.\t"
a.delete!('/\s/')  #=>  using single quote is unexpected, and you'll get "\tI have ome whitepace.\t"
```

Answer (score 7):

The gsub method will do just fine.
The gsub method can be called on a string and says:

```
a = "this is a string"
a = a.gsub(" ","")
puts a
#Output: thisisastring
```

The gsub method searches for every occurrence of the first argument
and replaces it with the second argument. In this case, it will replace every space within the string and remove it.

Another example:

```
b = "the white fox has a torn tail"
```

Let's replace every occurrence of the letter " t " with a capital " T "

```
b = b.gsub("t","T")
puts b 
#Output: The whiTe fox has a Torn Tail
```

Answer (score 7):

A lot of suggestions work here, but when I read your question and the specific line saying "removing all the whitespace", what came to my mind was this:

```
" a b c " => "abc"
```

And if that is really what is required, you can do this simple operation

```rb
wide_string = " a b c "

narrow_string = wide_string.delete(" ")

# you can pass all the different kinds 
# of whitespaces that you want to remove

puts narrow_string # => "abc"
```

Comment: Love it. Clean and intuitive. Should be performant as well, I would think.

Answer (score 6):

```
"asd sda sda sd".gsub(' ', '')
=> "asdsdasdasd"
```

Comment: but this removes only `spaces`, not all `white spaces`

Answer (score 5):

For behavior exactly matching PHP `trim`, the simplest method is to use the `String#strip` method, like so:

```
string = "  Many have tried; many have failed!    "
puts "Original [#{string}]:#{string.length}"
new_string = string.strip
puts "Updated  [#{new_string}]:#{new_string.length}"
```

Ruby also has an edit-in-place version, as well, called `String.strip!` (note the trailing '!').  This doesn't require creating a copy of the string, and can be significantly faster for some uses:

```
string = "  Many have tried; many have failed!    "
puts "Original [#{string}]:#{string.length}"
string.strip!
puts "Updated  [#{string}]:#{string.length}"
```

Both versions produce this output:

```
Original [  Many have tried; many have failed!    ]:40
Updated  [Many have tried; many have failed!]:34
```

I created a benchmark to test the performance of some basic uses of `strip` and `strip!`, as well as some alternatives.  The test is this:

```
require 'benchmark'

string = 'asdfghjkl'
Times = 25_000

a = Times.times.map {|n| spaces = ' ' * (1+n/4); "#{spaces}#{spaces}#{string}#{spaces}" }
b = Times.times.map {|n| spaces = ' ' * (1+n/4); "#{spaces}#{spaces}#{string}#{spaces}" }
c = Times.times.map {|n| spaces = ' ' * (1+n/4); "#{spaces}#{spaces}#{string}#{spaces}" }
d = Times.times.map {|n| spaces = ' ' * (1+n/4); "#{spaces}#{spaces}#{string}#{spaces}" }

puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION
puts "============================================================"
puts "Running tests for trimming strings"

Benchmark.bm(20) do |x|
  x.report("s.strip:")                 { a.each {|s| s = s.strip } }
  x.report("s.rstrip.lstrip:")         { a.each {|s| s = s.rstrip.lstrip } }
  x.report("s.gsub:")                  { a.each {|s| s = s.gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/, "") } }
  x.report("s.sub.sub:")               { a.each {|s| s = s.sub(/^\s+/, "").sub(/\s+$/, "") } }

  x.report("s.strip!")                 { a.each {|s| s.strip! } }
  x.report("s.rstrip!.lstrip!:")       { b.each {|s| s.rstrip! ; s.lstrip! } }
  x.report("s.gsub!:")                 { c.each {|s| s.gsub!(/^\s+|\s+$/, "") } }
  x.report("s.sub!.sub!:")             { d.each {|s| s.sub!(/^\s+/, "") ; s.sub!(/\s+$/, "") } }
end
```

These are the results:

```
ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-darwin14]
============================================================
Running tests for trimming strings
                           user     system      total        real
s.strip:               2.690000   0.320000   3.010000 (  4.048079)
s.rstrip.lstrip:       2.790000   0.060000   2.850000 (  3.110281)
s.gsub:               13.060000   5.800000  18.860000 ( 19.264533)
s.sub.sub:             9.880000   4.910000  14.790000 ( 14.945006)
s.strip!               2.750000   0.080000   2.830000 (  2.960402)
s.rstrip!.lstrip!:     2.670000   0.320000   2.990000 (  3.221094)
s.gsub!:              13.410000   6.490000  19.900000 ( 20.392547)
s.sub!.sub!:          10.260000   5.680000  15.940000 ( 16.411131)
```

Answer (score 3):

My personal preference is using the method `.tr`

as in:

```
string = "this is a string to smash together"

string.tr(' ', '') # => "thisisastringtosmashtogether"
```

Thanks to @FrankScmitt for pointing out that to make this delete *all* whitespace(not just spaces) you would need to write it as such:

```
string = "this is a string with tabs\t and a \nnewline"

string.tr(" \n\t", '') # => "thisisastringwithtabsandanewline"
```

Comment: but this removes only `spaces`, not `all white spaces`

Comment: To remove all white spaces (space, tab, newline), consider using `s.tr(" \t\n", '')` instead.

Comment: @Gavriel - I misread/misunderstood the question, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I added your correction to my answer, to more properly answer the OP's question. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do this as I wanted to use a records "title" as an id in the view but the titles had spaces.

a solution is:

```
record.value.delete(' ') # Foo Bar -> FooBar
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the game, but I remove trailing and leading whitespaces by using `strip!`. If you have an array, such as I did, I needed to iterate through the array and save it after the instance ended. The ! took care of this. This removed all whitespaces at the end or the beginning, not just the first leading or the last trailing.

For example:

```
array = ["hello ","   Melanie", "is", " new ", "to  ", " programming"]
array.each do |i|
  i.strip!
end
```

This would output to: ["hello","Melanie", "is", "new ", "to", "programming"]. I further explored/shared this [in a video I made to highlight this code for similar question I had](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef_hGfJGt3U).

I'm newer to programming and using strip did not work as it didn't save it to the array after the loop ended.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this to remove all spaces:

```
my_string = "   Foo  \t bar\nbaz quux \n   "

my_string.split.join
=> "Foobarbazquux"
```

Comment: Repost of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27602632/6243352 from 3 years earlier

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's `.scan()` and `.join()` methods of String can also help to overcome whitespace in string.

`scan(/\w+/).join` will remove all spaces and join the string

```
string = "White spaces in me".scan(/\w+/).join
=>"Whitespacesinme"
```

It is also removing space from left and right part of the string. Means `ltrim`, `rtrim` and `trim`. Just in case if someone has background over `C`, `FoxPro` or `Visual Basic` and jump in `Ruby`.

`2.1.6 :002 > string = " White spaces in me ".scan(/\w+/).join
 => "Whitespacesinme" 
2.1.6 :003 > string = " White spaces in me".scan(/\w+/).join
 => "Whitespacesinme" 
2.1.6 :004 > string = "White spaces in me ".scan(/\w+/).join
 => "Whitespacesinme" 
2.1.6 :005 >`

Comment: @AmitPandya Thank you so much for pointing out additional key points of  .scan() method. Appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
"ab c d efg hi ".split.map(&:strip)
```

in order to get this:

```
["ab, "c", "d", "efg", "hi"]
```

or if you want a single string, just use:

```
"ab c d efg hi ".split.join
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate spaces and keep single spaces intact, use:

```rb
"   Hello     World!   ".sqeeze(" ").strip
```

This is way faster than `split(" ").join` and other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If I am on Rails I use squish to remove all extra spaces in a string, in Ruby alone I would use strip to remove trailing spaces from beginning an d end of the string and finally if I want the same functionality as squish without having to import ActiveModel, I use this mystring.gsub(/\s{1,}/, ' ').strip