# Equivalent of {strip} in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an equivalent to Smarty's [`{strip}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl) in erb?

To clarify:

I'm not looking for `.strip`. Read the docs on Smarty's [`{strip}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.strip.tpl);

Whitespace **between** tags is significant and matters very much when you try to match widths and so on. For example, if you have this code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something else</li>
</ul>
```

and the `li`s have `display: inline`, there will be a space between them even if they have no `margin`. That space appears because of the whitespace between `</li>` and `<li>`. So, the only solution to not have that space between the `<li>`s is to do this:

```
<ul><li>Something</li><li>Something else</li></ul>
```

Which is pretty fugly and you end up with huge, unreadable lines when you start putting `<a>`s in the `<li>`s and so on.

Comment: I read the docs linked in your question but I don't understand when whitespace in the markup is significant? Is this outmoded functionality?

Comment: Are you looking for `.strip`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces

Comment: @Jeff Paquette: Not everything that can be generated is HTML (and doesn't care about whitespace).

Comment: @Jeff Paquette & @Piskvor, please check the edited question.

Comment: btw, the question should be "in ERB" or "in Haml" or any templating engine, not RoR

Comment: @KARASZI thanks, I've edited my question. I'm fairly new to rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the "traditional" method of putting spaces inside the tags (still valid XML):

```
<ul
  ><li><a href="#">bla</a></li
  ><li><a href="#">bla</a></li
></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options

- in [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/) you can do with [`>`](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_) and [`<`](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)
- in ERB the [`ERB::Compiler::TrimScanner`](http://rubydoc.info/docs/ruby-stdlib/1.9.2/ERB/Compiler/TrimScanner) maybe could help you out, but I've never used it. As far as I understand, it would look like this: `<%w capture do %>
  here comes your code with whitespaces
  <% end %>`

Comment: Interesting, but we don't use Haml so I can't use that.