# How do I remove a non-breaking space in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string that looks like this:

```
d = "foo\u00A0\bar"
```

When I check the length, it says that it is 7 characters long. I checked online and found out that it is a non-breaking space. Could someone show me how to remove all the non-breaking spaces in a string?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> d = "foo\u00A0\bar"
=> "foo \bar"
irb(main):002:0> d.gsub("\u00A0", "")
=> "foo\bar"
```

Comment: I had to remove a bunch of `&nbsp` characters from a string after a crawl without losing other space characters. This worked.

Answer (score 44):

In case you do not care about the non-breaking space specifically, but about *any* "special" unicode whitespace character that might appear in your string, you can replace it using the POSIX bracket expression for whitespace:

```
s.gsub(/[[:space:]]/, '')
```

These bracket expressions (as opposed to matchers like `\s`) do not only match ASCII characters, but all unicode characters of a class.

For more details see [the ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes)

Comment: Very useful when you have regular whitespace plus the pesky HTML `&nbsp` in the same string.

Answer (score 9):

It's an old thread but maybe it helps somebody.
I found myself looking for a solution to the same problem when I  discovered that strip doesn't do the job. I checked with method `ord` what the character was and used `chr` to represent it in `gsub`

```
2.2.3 :010 > 160.chr("UTF-8")
 => " " 
2.2.3 :011 > 160.chr("UTF-8").strip
 => " " 
2.2.3 :012 > nbsp = 160.chr("UTF-8")
 => " " 
2.2.3 :013 > nbsp.gsub(160.chr("UTF-8"),"")
 => ""
```

I couldn't understand why `strip` doesn't remove something that looked like a space to me so I checked [here](http://www.ascii-code.com) what ASCII 160 actually is.

Answer (score 2):

`d.gsub("\u00A0", "")` does not work in Ruby 1.8. Instead use `d.gsub(/\302\240/,"")`

See http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/understanding_m17n for lots more on the character encoding differences between 1.8 and 1.9.