# Using strip before field gets saved to databse in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to strip all whitespace in some fields before they go into my database.

I am using devise and have added additional fields to the members table (used members instead of users).

On my sign up form I have some fields such as telephone and address however I would like to strip all whitespace for certain fields like `:telephone`, `:mobile` and `:emergency_number`.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `before_save`!

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :strip_whitespace

private
  def strip_whitespace
    self.telephone.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
    # etc...
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to @Chowlett's solution

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :strip_whitespace

private:
  def strip_whitespace
    self.telephone.join('')
    # etc...
  end
end
```