# How can I remove all blank-spaces?

Tags: ruby

My file part is

```
string = " hello!  ";
puts string.replace(" ")
```

but it is replacing hello! too

i want only hello! to be as in TRIM() function

Comment: Kinda repetitive question.

Check here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces

Comment: No research effort. You know about `trim`, Googling "ruby trim" would have led you straight to the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation on [`String#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-replace) for why it *doesn't* work as expected (this is an unfortunate function with a confusing name resulting from the fact that Ruby strings are mutable):

> *Replaces the [entire] contents [of the String]* and taintedness of str with the corresponding values in other_str.

You probably want [`String#strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-strip) which behaves like "TRIM" in other contexts:

> Returns a copy of str with *leading and trailing whitespace removed*.

```
" Hello world! ".strip  # => "Hello world!"
```

(If you wish to remove spaces *everywhere*, see `String#gsub` - I'll let you look that one up.)

Answer (score 2):

You can `string.gsub(" ", "")` and get `hello!` finally.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-tr)

```
irb(main):001:0> s = " hello!  "
=> " hello!  "
irb(main):002:0> s.tr(" ","")
=> "hello!"
irb(main):003:0>
```