# Remove space from query params in url dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I want to remove the space in query params in the request url in ruby

Here is my sample request url:-

```
URL = 'www.test.com/a?q1=john&q2=US&q3= 92832832&q4=test&q5= foo'
```

I want to my output as below:-

```
URL = 'www.test.com/a?q1=john&q2=US&q3=92832832&q4=test&q5=foo'
```

Comment: Use `String#delete` method with `' '` as argument.

Comment: Where does the space come from in the first place?

Comment: @Stefan space occurs in more than one query params in url.

Comment: @karan yes, I can see the spaces, but where do these spaces come from?

Comment: @Stefan I don't know where it comes from. Might be user ip problem.

Comment: @karan are these the parameters that are passed to your rails controller?

Comment: @Stefan No.Its not passed to my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trimming the white space. This can be achieved as stated by Joel:

> If you want to remove only leading and trailing whitespace (like PHP's trim) you can use `.strip`, but if you want to remove all whitespace, you can use `.gsub(/\s+/, "")` instead.
>   ([Ruby function to remove all white spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces))

Answer (score 1):

To remove whitespace you can use the following on the string

```
URL = 'www.test.com/a?q1=john&q2=US&q3= 92832832&q4=test&q5= foo'.gsub(/\s+/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

url = 'www.test.com/a?q1=john&q2=US&q3= 92832832&q4=test&q5= foo'.gsub!(/\s+/, "")