# Remove all space characters from string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, integer, spaces

How do I remove all spaces and white-space characters from a string?

I have tried the following:

```
number = params[:phone][:number]
number.delete(' ').gsub(/\D/)
```

However, if I enter a number with a space I still get something like `0000 000`. It's supposed to return `0000000`, i.e., no spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby function to remove all white spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces)

Comment: I looked at those and the code didn't work as I wanted, plus they were more concerned about trim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the destructive delete method. #delete!

```
number.delete!(' ').gsub(/\D/)
```

Comment: hey thanks! just out of curiosity can you explain the difference between delete and delete! methods?

Comment: Also I noticed that when I ran gsub with a word over a number (i.e. it would be nil) because it was nil it would cause an error so I used `number.delete!(' ') number.gsub(/\D/)`

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. the bang (!) usually indicates that the method is destructive, meaning that the operation acts on itself and changes original value. string = 'abc'; string.delete('a') would return 'bc' but the 'string' variable would still hold the value 'abc'. A destructive method would change the variable 'string' to 'bc'

Comment: Thanks, that actually helps a great deal - clear understanding of it now. :)