# Remove " " from line Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a loop which read lines from text file :

```
 text = File.open("file.txt").read
  text.gsub!(/\n\r?/, "\n", )
  text.each_line do |line|
  # do something with line
  end
```

And in each iteration I get line with " " in the end of line : "word ", and I need get just "word"

How fix my problem?

`ll = line.clone.sub!(" ", "")` - returns nil

Comment: Voting to re-open because we've just closed [the question that this is marked as a duplicate of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces) (that question is vague).  If there is another non-vague question that this is a duplicate of, we can remark this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [`String#strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/String.html#method-i-strip) or one of the similar methods to remove whitespace. In this example [`String#rstrip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/String.html#method-i-rstrip) seems to be an option:

```
text.each_line do |line|
  sanitized_line = line.rstrip
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line.gsub!(/\s+/, "") - fixed my problem.
```

Comment: This will remove all whitespace, not only at the end of the string.