# Trying to remove spaces from a string RUBY

Tags: ruby

as the title says, i'm trying to write a function to remove spaces. This is where i am so far, but it seems i'm missing something.

```
def remove(x)
  if x.include? " "
    x.gsub!(/ /,"")
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, for some reason if the space is at the end of the string, it does not remove it.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn the language at the moment, but it seems in codewars it won't work.

"It should work for random inputs too, test for 1q -  Expected: "1q", instead got: nil "

Comment: Remove the `if` and use not banged version. The banged version mutates the variable _and_ return `nil` if no substitution was made. `x.delete(' ')` will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby function to remove all white spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces)

Comment: If you browse the instance methods of the class [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html), you will find three methods that [fit the bill](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fit-the-bill): `gsub`, `tr` and `delete`. Which is best here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're probably checking the output of the function, right?

You have something like

```
remove('1q')
=> nil
```

This is because the `remove` method isn't returning anything if there's no space found. Just make sure you return the modified value.

```
def remove(x)
  if x.include? " "
    x.gsub!(/ /,"")
  end
  x  # this is the last executed command and so will be the return value of the method
end
```

And now you'll see

```
 remove('1q')
=> "1q"
```

Note that your method actually mutates the object, so you don't really need to test what's returned, you can just inspect the variable with the original value.  Do...

```
test_value = 'My carrot'
remove(test_value)

p test_value
=> "Mycarrot"
```

Finally, as has been pointed out, you don't need to surround it in an `if` clause, the `gsub!` will work only on any spaces it finds and will otherwise do nothing.

```
def remove(x)
  x.gsub!(' ', '')
  x
end
```

Note that you still need to return the `x` variable as if `gsub!` does nothing, it returns `nil`

The method `gsub` (on the other hand) doesn't mutate, it will always return a new value which will be the string with any substitutions made, so you could do

```
def remove(x)
  x.gsub(' ','')
end
```

And this will always return a value regardless of whether substitution occured... but the original object will be unchanged. (The returned value will have a different `object_id`)

Answer (score 1):

more simple, you can do:

```
def remove_blank_spaces(str)
  str.delete(' ')
end
```

Other option:

```
def remove_blank_spaces(str)
  str.gsub(' ', '')
end
```