# Ruby on rails, how to remove white-space from japanese word?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.4

I am trying to remove white-space from japanese word.

```
input   "かいしゃ（会社）"
output  "かいしゃ(会社)"
```

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces

Comment: Yes. i have seen, but it didn't work well in japanese words.

Comment: @vvp.rb: next time mention the research you've done. Saves everyone's time and can prevent downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space here is consumed by the parentheses. They are not your regular ASCII parentheses, they are of the ["full width"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff08/index.htm) flavor.

If you want to replace them with ASCII parentheses, you can do it like this:

```
compact_input = input.gsub("\uFF08", '(') # and a similar step for the closing parenthesis
```

<sup>Although this might make your string look weird in japanese (I don't know the language well enough, so can't say)</sup>

Comment: or `input.tr('（）', '()')`

Comment: I have did for closing parenthesis, it didn't works

Comment: @vvp.rb: then you did something wrong. Have you used the correct code for the full-width right parenthesis?

Comment: @Stefan: while that undoubtedly should work, I think it's confusing at best

Comment: what about `input.tr("\uFF08\uFF09", '()')` then?

Comment: @Stefan: yes, I like this one better!

Comment: The following may help provide insight for readers: `s = "かいしゃ（会社）"`, 
`s.encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>`, `a = s.codepoints #=>[12363, 12356, 12375, 12419, 65288, 20250, 31038, 65289]`, `a.map { |cp| [cp].pack('U*')} #=> ["か", "い", "し", "ゃ", "（", "会", "社", "）"]`.