# Fluentd does not parse nested json array

Tags: fluentd

I have the following json message on Fluentd input

`{"foo":{"bar":{"abc":"[\n  {\n  \"ip\":\"192.168.1.1\",\n  \"hostname\":\"pc\",\n  \"mac\":\"01:02:03:04:05:06\"\n}  \n]"}}}`

And want to get the output message

```
{"foo":{"bar":{"abc":[{"ip":"192.168.1.1", "hostname":"pc", "mac":"01:02:03:04:05:06}]"}}}
```

I'm trying to parse it with the filter

```
<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name foo
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field false
  <parse>
    @type multi_format
    <pattern>
      format json
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
      format none
    </pattern>
  </parse>
</filter>
```

But without any effect. The output is the same as the input.

When I try

```
<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name $['foo']['bar']['abc']
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
</filter>

<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>
```

it "works" but of course I get only

```
[{"ip":"192.168.1.1","hostname":"ps","mac":"01:02:03:04:05:06}]
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: What I understood is that you're getting messages that include escape characters and you want to clean those, right? What is the `source`? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67505981/edit) and add the `source` section.

Comment: @Azeem Yes, you are right about "clean the escape characters" `<sourse>` doesn't matter in this case and could be anything - dummy, sample, forward etc.

Comment: Well, if you're getting hardcoded escape characters as shown in the example above, one way to clean/convert those can be with the `record_transformer` filter plugin by enabling Ruby. You can give that a try.

Comment: @Azeem but how? could you suggest any code?

Comment: Please refer to the docs: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#enable_ruby. In the block, you can use ruby code. For example, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634750/ruby-function-to-remove-all-white-spaces.

Comment: @Azeem did you try it by yourself? I can exclude `\n` but it doesn't work for `\"` sequence

Comment: @Azeem `record_transformer` creates a new pair key:value, what is not suitable. `modified ${(record['log']['foo']['bar']['abc']).gsub(/\s/, "")}`  works for `\n` removing.
`record_modifier` could replace key value but it require regex, what is not possible in the case because "abc" key value are changing

Comment: Tested on `irb`: `s = '{"foo":{"bar":{"abc":"[\n  {\n  \"ip\":\"192.168.1.1\",\n  \"hostname\":\"pc\",\n  \"mac\":\"01:02:03:04:05:06\"\n}  \n]"}}}'; puts s.gsub(/(\\n)|(\\)|(\s+)/, '');`. Output: `{"foo":{"bar":{"abc":"[{"ip":"192.168.1.1","hostname":"pc","mac":"01:02:03:04:05:06"}]"}}}`

Comment: With `record_transformer`, you can change the complete message i.e. `message ${ record['message'].gsub(...) }`.

Comment: Just tested with `message ${ record['message'].gsub(/(\\n)|(\\)|(\s+)/, '') }` and here's the output `2021-05-17 16:19:58.013453802 +0500 test.*: {"message":"{\"foo\":{\"bar\":{\"abc\":\"[{\"ip\":\"192.168.1.1\",\"hostname\":\"pc\",\"mac\":\"01:02:03:04:05:06\"}]\"}}}"}`.

Comment: I have just posted an answer with all the steps to reproduce this. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this parses unparsed nested json

```
<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name $['foo']['bar']['abc']
  hash_value_field parsed_abc
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>

<filter **>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    parsed_abc ${record['foo']['bar']['abc'] = record['parsed_abc']}
  </record>
  remove_keys parsed_abc
</filter>
```